# Selected Radio Button value isn't being passed with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using this to collected the values of a few fields into one field. Everything is being passed properly except for the radio button value.

```
 jQuery('#donate-form').submit(function() {
 jQuery('[name="COMMENT2"]').val('Donation: ' + jQuery('.active [name="USER2"]').val() + ': ' + jQuery('input[name="reason"]:checked').val() + ': ' + jQuery('[name="sponsorName"]').val() + 
                ' Occasion: ' + jQuery('.active [name="occasion"]').val() + ' Donated By: ' + jQuery('.active [name="donatedBy"]').val() + ' Use: ' + jQuery('input[name="day"]:checked').val() + 
                ' Date: ' + jQuery('[name="date"]').val() + ' Contact Me: ' + jQuery('[name="contactMe"]').val()); 
 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="row"><label for="amount">Amount:</label><input id="amount 2" name="AMOUNT" type="text" class="required"/><br/></div>
    <div class="row">
        <input name="reason" type="radio" id="memory" value="In Memory of" /><label for="memory">In Memory of</label>
        <input name="reason" type="radio" id="honor" value="In Honor of"/><label for="honor">In Honor of</label>
        <input name="reason" type="radio" id="noOccasion" value="No Occasion"/><label for="noOccasion">No Occasion</label>
    <br/></div>
    <div class="row"><label for="sponsorName">Name(s):</label>
        <input id="sponsorName" name="sponsorName" type="text"/><br/></div>
    <div class="row"><label for="occasion">Occasion:</label>
        <input id="occasion" name="occasion" type="text"/><br/></div>
    <div class="row"><label for="donatedBy">Donated By:</label>
        <input id="donatedBy" name="donatedBy" type="text"/><br/></div>
    <div class="row">Make a request to reserver your special day:</div>
    <div class="row">
        <input name="day" type="radio" id="English" value="English Date"/>
            <label for="English">English Date</label>
        <input name="day" type="radio" id="Hebrew" value="Hebrew Date"/>
            <label for="Hebrew">Hebrew Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input id="date" name="date" type="text"/><br/></div>
    <div class="row"><input type="checkbox" name="contactMe" value="yes" id="contactMe" /><label class="long" for="contactMe">Contact me for acknowledgement notices.</label></div>
    <div class="row"><label for="comments">Comments</label><textarea id="comments" name="COMMENT1" cols="38" rows="1" style="margin-left:0"></textarea></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="COMMENT2" value=""></input><input type="hidden" name="DESCRIPTION"></input>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please format the code better, this is absurd

Comment: I thought this is a forum where people help each other. Please explain what's absurd about this.

Comment: You don't seem to be using indentation or line breaks consistently.  It's not great formatting but I've seen much worse on here, so don't take it too personally...

Comment: are you running this code on document ready?

Comment: sorry I edited the code to show when its being run

Answer (score 0):

When is this code being run?  The way you are attempting to get the value from the radio button should work assuming you only want checked values...

I have setup a basic demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ygxyt/) that shows this.  Just click on the "English Date" radio button to see it in action.

Comment: It also depends on when the code is being run.  If it's on document ready then it's possible that no radio button is selected which would explain why he's not seeing a value...

Comment: that can be the case, i have asked.